# How to make this select more efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I'm working on my new code which should:
Make a report as a procedure cointains pole: (so read it as MAKE PROCEDURE WHICH display:)

1. Id
2. JobNo
3. IMEI
4. DataRejestracji (registration date f.e) in specyfic format - in
   table its diffrenet
5. Akcesoria (full names of accesory using one after other using ","
   from Jobs.Accessories and use SPLIT function
6. Id_JobsArch ( (Jobs.ID=JobsArch.ID_Jobs and only one newest date
   record should be displayed)
7. Naprawiony (if pole Jobs.RepairDate is empty then No if else YES)
8. FLSymptomCodes (JobsSpares.ID_JOBS=Jobs.ID >
   JobsSpares.ID_FLSymptomCodes=FLSymptomCodes.ID, one after other
   using ";"
9. NazwaHosta (hostname)

Procedure has 3 input parameters on start `OD`, `DO`, `IMEI`
WHEN U LET THEM FREE (empty) it should display 100 newest Job record

It did all work fine for me however my supervisor wants me to optimize it not using `IF ELSE` and he suggests me to use WHERE as better option.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE raport @OD DATE,  @DO DATE, @IMEI nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
IF ISNULL(@IMEI, '') <> '' AND ISNULL(@OD,'') <>'' AND ISNULL(@DO,'') <>''
BEGIN

SELECT  top 1 
        Z.ID,
        Z.JobNo,
        Z.IMEI, 
        CAST(Z.DateBooked AS DATE) AS DataRejestracji, 
        Akcesoria = STUFF(
                            (
                                SELECT ',' + A.Accessory
                                    FROM    dbo.SPLIT(Z.Accessories, '/') new
                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Accessories A ON new.items = A.Skrot COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT    



                                  FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
                    ) ,
    --JA.ID_Jobs, 
    JA.ID as ID_JobsArch,       
    FLSymptomsCodes = STUFF
                        (
                            (
                                SELECT ',' + FS.FLSymptomCode
                        FROM JobsSpares JS
                        INNER JOIN FLSymptomCodes FS ON JS.ID_FLSymptomCodes = FS.ID
                        WHERE js.id_jobs=Z.ID
                                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
                        , 1, 1, ''),
    @@servername    AS [Nazwa Hosta],
     CASE  WHEN  Z.RepairDate IS NULL THEN 'NIE'
                    ELSE 'TAK'
                    END AS Naprawiony

FROM ZTEPro.dbo.Jobs AS Z
INNER JOIN dbo.JobsArch JA
ON Z.ID=JA.ID_Jobs

WHERE   
        Z.IMEI = @IMEI AND 
        Z.DateBooked BETWEEN @OD AND @DO
ORDER BY Id_JobsArch DESC
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT  top 100 
        Z.ID,
        Z.JobNo,
        Z.IMEI, 
        CAST(Z.DateBooked AS DATE) AS DataRejestracji, 
        Akcesoria = STUFF(
                            (
                                SELECT ',' + A.Accessory
                                    FROM    dbo.SPLIT(Z.Accessories, '/') new
                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Accessories A ON new.items = A.Skrot COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT    



                                  FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
                    ) ,
    --JA.ID_Jobs, 
    JA.ID as ID_JobsArch,
    JA.ActData,         
    FLSymptomsCodes = STUFF
                        (
                            (
                                SELECT ',' + FS.FLSymptomCode
                        FROM JobsSpares JS
                        INNER JOIN FLSymptomCodes FS ON JS.ID_FLSymptomCodes = FS.ID
                        WHERE js.id_jobs=Z.ID
                                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
                        , 1, 1, ''),
    @@servername    AS [Nazwa Hosta],
     CASE  WHEN  Z.RepairDate IS NULL THEN 'NIE'
                    ELSE 'TAK'
                    END AS Naprawiony

FROM ZTEPro.dbo.Jobs AS Z
INNER JOIN dbo.JobsArch JA
ON Z.ID=JA.ID_Jobs


ORDER BY JA.ActData DESC
END


END;
```

Maybe `WHERE` clauses... but I'm out of ideas.
Also no idea what more details I should put here.

Comment: Eff?  What does that mean?>

Comment: efficient ofc. sry mates im new here and new in sql... feeling uncomfortable.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a conditional `TOP` clause like this (no need to use the `ISNULL` function):

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT case when @IMEI is not null AND @OD is not null AND @DO is not null then 1 else 100 end)
```

You can also adjust your `WHERE` clause to only apply when all your variables are not null:

```
WHERE   (@IMEI is null or @OD is null or @DO is null) or
        (Z.IMEI = @IMEI AND 
        Z.DateBooked BETWEEN @OD AND @DO)
```

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT  top (select case when @IMEI is not null AND @OD is not null AND @DO is not null then 1 else 100 end) 
        Z.ID,
        Z.JobNo,
        Z.IMEI, 
        CAST(Z.DateBooked AS DATE) AS DataRejestracji, 
        Akcesoria = STUFF(
                            (
                                SELECT ',' + A.Accessory
                                    FROM    dbo.SPLIT(Z.Accessories, '/') new
                                        INNER JOIN dbo.Accessories A ON new.items = A.Skrot COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT    



                                  FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
                    ) ,
    --JA.ID_Jobs, 
    JA.ID as ID_JobsArch,  
    JA.ActData,     
    FLSymptomsCodes = STUFF
                        (
                            (
                                SELECT ',' + FS.FLSymptomCode
                        FROM JobsSpares JS
                        INNER JOIN FLSymptomCodes FS ON JS.ID_FLSymptomCodes = FS.ID
                        WHERE js.id_jobs=Z.ID
                                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
                        , 1, 1, ''),
    @@servername    AS [Nazwa Hosta],
     CASE  WHEN  Z.RepairDate IS NULL THEN 'NIE'
                    ELSE 'TAK'
                    END AS Naprawiony

FROM ZTEPro.dbo.Jobs AS Z
INNER JOIN dbo.JobsArch JA
ON Z.ID=JA.ID_Jobs
WHERE   (@IMEI is null or @OD is null or @DO is null) or
        (Z.IMEI = @IMEI AND 
        Z.DateBooked BETWEEN @OD AND @DO)
ORDER BY Id_JobsArch DESC
```

This probably won't run noticeably faster than your original query, but at least it's more compact.

Comment: i might do smth wrong but this not working for me as querry with "if, else"

Comment: Do you mean it's giving an error, or it isn't giving the correct results?

Comment: working 99% but not displaying JA.ID as ID_JobsArch,  dont know why

Comment: You mean it's returning the correct rows, but the ID_JobsArch column is blank?

Comment: ID_JobsArch not even appear in result table.. dont understand this...